# Kingroot how to uninstall

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-c3-dual

I downloaded kingroot downloaded the root access and was working properly. I uninstalled it then again instsalled it (3 times). Now I have root access and now I want to remove it. I tried my old way ( uninstall kingroot from the settings in kingroot) but now it is showing error. I tried system cleaner apps. Those didnt work. Now what should I do to unroot. ( while rooting I didnt do anything other than installing kingroot I didnt unlock bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to unroot your phone with SuperSU.

Comment: I tried to convert into SuperSu using SuperSu me. But they told me that at maximum it will take 5 min. I kept it all night nothing happened

Comment: And about unrooting using SuperSu then how to do it